# php push notification to specific user via nodejs (socket.io) and redis

Tags: php, notifications, redis, socket.io, predis

I trying to push notification to specific client with nodejs and redis but emitting the notification to the requested user is not working

my codes in php and nodejs and client is below:

```
//Nodejs Server ---------------------------
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
var redis = require('redis');
var $clients = {};

var $notifySubscribe = redis.createClient();
var $loginUserSubscribe = redis.createClient();
$notifySubscribe.subscribe('notify');
$loginUserSubscribe.subscribe('loginUser');

$notifySubscribe.on('message', function($channel, $message) {
    var $data = JSON.parse($message);
    if($data.userId in $clients){
        $clients[$data.userId].emit('updateNotifications', '+1');
    }
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    $loginUserSubscribe.on('message', function($channel, $message){
        var $data = JSON.parse($message);
        if(!($data.userId in $clients)){
            $clients[$data.userId] = socket;
        }
    });

});

//Client ----------------------------------
socketIo.on('updateNotifications', function($count){
    alert($count);
});

//Php Server ------------------------------
$data = array('userId' => 20584, 'username' => 'mohammadsaleh');
$this->__redis->publish("notify", json_encode($data));
```

Comment: What's not working? can you describe expected behavior and actual behavior?

Comment: $clients[$data.userId].emit('updateNotifications', '+1'); does not working, so in the client does not alert()